# Días laborables en Oracle sql

Tags: oracle, sql, date

Buen día, podría alguien ayudarme a saber como poder aumentar cinco días a una fecha de una tabla, siendo que no tome los días sábados ni domingos, ya que solo necesito los laborables.
Siendo que al final se muestre la fecha en la cual queda.

Comment: Bienvenida a SO en español , para poder ayudarte mejor podrías compartir lo que llevas hecho ya? Un saludo :)

Comment: Para hablar de días laborales, necesitas una tabla de calendario que indique los días laborales y los días no laborales. De otra forma, cualquier solución que no la use, tendrá un problema cuando tengas que incorporar festivos.